# Linq to EF doesn't select foreign keys

Tags: database, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So I have two tables, Table1 and Table2.  Table one has an integer that is a foreign key to the identity column of Table2, I will call this FK Table2ID.  If I perform this query:

```
var objs = (from t in DataContext.Table1 select t).Single();
```

objs.Table2.Table2ID is null.  However I can easily select the value using a query like this:

```
var Table2ID = (from t in DataContext.Table1.Table2.Table2ID).Single();
```

How can I select back the value of the FK in Table1 using the first query, and why is it not returning automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like lazy loading is turned off for some reason, so try `Include` - this should work:

```
var objs = (from t in DataContext.Table1.Include("Table2") select t).Single();
```

What EF version are you working with ? Is this code first or database first?

Also when you are accessing related entities through a navigation property you do not use the FK - you should be able to access `objs.Table2.Id` provided `Id` is the primary key of the `Table2` entity.

**Edit:**

It sounds like you didn't tick off to include foreign keys in your model - make sure to add it. If you right click your model and select "Update model from database..." you will get the following dialog.

[image]

Comment: The database was designed first, I am converting to EF.  If I include Table2 is it going to select back all of the data?  I only really need the value of the Fk in Table1.

Comment: @Payson: The FK column is part of the `Table1` entity - in your example it should be accessible as `objs.Table2Id` - do you just want the FK or the corresponding `Table2` entity itself?

Comment: @BrokenGlass unfortunately I do not have the option to select objs.Table2Id, however I have every other column in the table, and a pathway to the FK via objs.Table2.Table2Id.

Comment: Is `Table2Id` the primary key of `Table2` ?

Comment: @Payson: Updated my answer - did you include the foreign key columns in your model?

Comment: @BrokenGlass Table2Id is not the primary key.  I went to generate a new entity model and the option to include foreign keys in the model is grayed out, the tooltip message says: "This functionality is not available in the target framework currently specified for the project."

Comment: Well what target framework did you pick? Make sure you have ".NET framework 4" selected in your project properties (and not i.e. client profile)

Comment: @BrokenGlass Yep that was it - Thanks and I'll add some bounty points on this before I select this as the answer, both approaches worked out great!

Comment: @BrokenGlass sorry I didn't have the option to add bounty points but your help was well worth them, thanks again.